# Apache failed to start

Tags: linux, apache, apache2, fedora, bugzilla

Please help me solving this problem I don't know why this is coming...before two days it was coming fine...but after uninstalling lampp I'm getting this error.But I have another apache installed.

> Starting httpd: Syntax error on line 997 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:
>   Can't locate object method "set_max_unshared_size" via package "Apache2::SizeLimit" at /var/www/html/bugzilla/mod_perl.pl line 56.\nCompilation failed in require at (eval 2) line 1.\n

Any suggestion will be great thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks you have to install some more packages to resolve this error you can solve it by installing `mod_perl-devel` and `httpd-devel` for your OS.

See this [link](http://freevps.us/thread-7213.html)

Comment: i read that one,in that case he is installing one different module so that solution will work for him only :(

Comment: he is facing the same error so i think installing those packages and restaring apache should fix the problem for you

Comment: i found the error... I need to install apache size limit package.Do u know how to do that in command

Comment: Yes you can use this link http://letitknow.wordpress.com/2012/05/08/bugzilla-install-apache-sizelimit/

Answer (score 0):

This is more a suggestion on troubleshooting steps rather than a one line sloution. I think you should start by confirming that your environment meet the requirements to run `Bugzilla` using `mod_perl`. If not, you should be able to use `mod_cgi` as far as I know.

My suggestion is to start following the installation instructions for `Buzgilla` and confirm the correct versions of Perl and it's modules are used/installed. This is described in the [Installtion - Perl Modules](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/tip/en/html/installation.html#install-perlmodules) section of the `Bugzilla` documentation. Basically you can run `checksetup.pl` provided with the `Bugzilla` installation.

If all the above is OK the second step would be to confirm that the Apache configuration is correct, and this is described in the [Configuration section](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/tip/en/html/configuration.html) of the `Bugzilla` documentation, and more specifically under *2.2.4. Web server*.

Hope this help you forward in troubleshooting this issue.

Comment: thnks for the links let me check and i ll thank you again if it works :D

Comment: Hey dude thanks for your link at least im trying something now.
But Do you know how to install this module 
Checking for     Apache-SizeLimit (v0.96)     not found

Comment: I have not used it myself, but I guess you can find out how here (I assume version 0.97 is OK): http://search.cpan.org/~phred/Apache-SizeLimit-0.97/

Answer (score 0):

```
$ grep setmax /usr/lib64/perl5/Apache2/SizeLimit.pm 
# setmax can be called from within a CGI/Registry script to tell the httpd
...
sub setmax_unshared {
```

So its `setmax_unshared` not `set_max_unshared_size`

Answer (score 0):

if you got error: "**Can't locate ModPerl/MM.pm**", try this:

```
/usr/bin/perl install-module.pl ModPerl::MM

/usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Apache2::SizeLimit

/usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Linux::Pid
```